# How can I select unanswered questions?

Tags: mysql, sql, self-join

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `qanda` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `subject` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `body_html` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `related` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `amount` decimal(11,0) DEFAULT NULL,
  `closed` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `CloserId` varchar(500) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `AcceptedAnswer` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `aadate` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `keywords` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `visibility` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `editor_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `date_time` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `edited_at` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated_at` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `activated_story` enum('سوال شده','ویرایش شده','جواب داده شده','') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `activator_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

This table stores both questions and answers. Here is my current query which provides a list of all questions and sort them based on the vote:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0)
           FROM votes vv
           WHERE qanda.id = vv.post_id) AS total_votes
FROM qanda
WHERE type = 0 -- "type=0" means questions
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
LIMIT :j,11;
```

Now I need one more condition on the `WHERE` clause to exclude questions that have answer(s). I guess I need a `self-join`. But I don't know how can I write a `join` on the `where` clause. Is there any suggestion?

Comment: It is very strange to have both questions and answers in one table, as these are different things. You should change your data model and make this separate tables.

Comment: As to your question: How do I see which question refers an answer to?

Comment: you can write an "and not exists (your query)" in where clause. as you have question id with you.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner That's what stackoverflow done! https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/edit/676264

Comment: @ThorstenKettner There is `related` column. which is `null` for question and the id of its own question for answers.

Comment: So `type = 0` mean question, but `related = null` also mean question. That is why you should put answer and questions in two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `NOT IN` to exclude IDs that were answered:

```
SELECT *, (SELECT COALESCE(sum(vv.value),0)
           FROM votes vv
           WHERE qanda.id = vv.post_id) AS total_votes
FROM qanda
WHERE type = 0
AND id NOT IN (SELECT related FROM quanda WHERE type <> 0)
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
LIMIT :j,11;
```

Comment: There is actually nothing clever about this. We use `[NOT] IN` (or `[NOT] EXISTS` when it gets more complicated) when we check whether data exists in a dataset (in your case: whether the questien exists in the answered ones). We only use joins instead when we want combined results. (Or anti joins as shown by Juan Carlos Oropeza, when the DBMS has performance issues with `NOT IN`/`NOT EXISTS`. MySQL was once known for being weak on `IN` expressions, but I guess that's a thing of the past now.)

Comment: There is a problem .. in your approach, when a question has multiple answers, it causes multiple duplicate in `NOT IN ( ... )` .. Am I right?

Comment: @MartinAJ That isnt a problem, because when the db engine find a match, the `NOT IN` return false. Multiples match doesn't make the comparison more false.

Comment: yes, the result will be the same, but I guess in this case there is some waste processing.. Isn't there? I mean can I use `distinct` like this? `. . . NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT related FROM ... )` ?

Comment: You *can* use `DISTINCT`, but you shouldn't. Making the values distinct first *may*  be the fastest approach and may be not. We don't know. Let the DBMS find the best plan. Don't try to force a way that you consider best. If the DBMS thinks that performing a `DISTINCT` is the best option it will silently do so, anyway.

Comment: Ok well, I've some personal questions: How old are you? Are you male or female? where are you from? How long have you worked on SQL queries?

Answer (score 1):

With a `SELF JOIN`, you try to match a question with any answer. If you don't find a match you will get `NULL` so you will get the questions without answers.

```
SELECT questions.*
FROM qanda questions
LEFT JOIN qanda answers
  ON question.id = answers.related
WHERE questions.type = 0 
  AND answers.id IS NULL
```